# Cassandra seconday index vs materialized view

Tags: cassandra

I'm modeling my table for Cassandra 3.0+. The objective is to build a table that store user's activities, here what i've done so far:
(*userid* come from another database Mysql)

```
CREATE TABLE activity (
    userid int,
    type int,
    remoteid text,
    time timestamp,
    imported timestamp,
    visibility int,
    title text,
    description text,
    img text,
    customfields MAP<text,text>,
PRIMARY KEY (userid, type, remoteid, time, imported))
```

This are the main queries that i use:

```
SELECT * FROM activity WHERE userid = ? AND remoteid = ?;
SELECT * FROM activity WHERE userid = ? AND type = ? AND LIMIT 10;
```

Now i need to add the column `visibility` on the second query. So, from what i've learned around, i can choose between a *secondary index* or a *materialized view*.
This are the facts:

- Here i've one partition per user and inside there are thousands of rows (activities).
- I use **always** the partition key (*userid*) in all my query to access the data.
- the global number of activities are 30 millions, growing up.
- `visibility` column has low cardinality (just 3 value) and could be updated, but rarely.

So what should i choose? materialized view or index? I know that index with low cardinality are bad choice, but my query include always the partition key and a limit, so maybe is not that bad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are always going to use the partition key I recommend using secondary indexes.

Materialized views are better when you do not know the partition key

***References:***

***Principal Article!***

• [Cassandra Secondary Index Preview #1](http://rustyrazorblade.com/2016/02/cassandra-secondary-index-preview-1/)

Here is a comparison with the Materialized Views and the secondary indices

• [Materialized View Performance in Cassandra 3.x](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/materialized-view-performance-in-cassandra-3-x)

And here is where the PK is known is more effective to use an index

• [Cassandra Native Secondary Index Deep Dive](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-native-secondary-index-deep-dive)

Comment: You write: *Materialized views are better when you do not know the partition key.* However, this contradicts what Tyler Hobbs wrote in this [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10226): *The base table's partition key will often be a good choice for the MV partition key as well.*

Comment: Yes but the question is, when is it better to use one or the other?

The materialized views the information is stored as a new table, which leads to more memory in Disk, the secondary index only stores PK in a "new table" and this table is stored only in the node where PK.
That is my point of view and I support the above documentation that in summary is that.